# How to search a collection in Azure Mongo CosmosDB with 3 fields with not dupplicate data

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an example like this

```
"lastRun": [
{
  "_id": "64e03c733",
  "A": "valueA",
  "B": "valueA",
  "C": "valueA",
},
{
  "_id": "64e03c734",
  "A": "valueA",
  "B": "valueB",
  "C": "valueC",
},
{
  "_id": "64e03c735",
  "A": "valueA",
  "B": "valueA",
  "C": "valueB",
}
```

Above is an example of data, but there are many data like that, I want to search all data with  3 fields with the condition is not duplicated data. How can I do that in Azure MongoCosmosDB? in MySQL we can search it like `c.field1 <> c.field2 AND c.field1 <> c.field3 AND c.field2 <> c.field3`
but in Mongo CosmosDB we search by `{}` JSON format
Please help me, thanks

Comment: Like this? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xQ5xToxSv9a)

Comment: hi @YongShun, yes it's like your example above, I already try that condition but it's still through for me a collection that value A = value B. Do you have any other way to make it more perfect, thank alot

Comment: when all three fields have same data, those are to be filtered out. - Is this your requirement? Here, Items with ids `64e03c734` and `64e03c735` are to be displayed, right?

Comment: @Aswin no sir, only this 64e03c734 is displayed as I expected

Comment: Is `"lastRun"` showing a collection, or is that one field in a single document?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you expected that you want the documents containing three fields that must have a unique value.

The concept should be:

1. Find the document with any of the fields that have the same value.
2. Negate the condition (1).

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $not: {
      $or: [
        {
          $eq: [
            "$A",
            "$B"
          ]
        },
        {
          $eq: [
            "$A",
            "$C"
          ]
        },
        {
          $eq: [
            "$B",
            "$C"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7CCMwy_PytL)

---

Another solution you may look for is comparing the `$size` of the array with these elements against the size of the array with unique elements.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $size: [
          [
            "$A",
            "$B",
            "$C"
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        $size: [
          {
            $setUnion: [
              [
                "$A",
                "$B",
                "$C"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7S5v-fZJHoz)

Comment: Thanks @Yong Shun but that's not what I expected, my expected result is only 64e03c734 is displayed

Comment: Revised answer. Please check.

Comment: Thank you, but I dont know in my data it's still return the same with A and B

Comment: I don't get it, actually based on your expected result. The first query that post in the comment should be worked. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pgX-p_q7yH0), which any of the values can't be matched.

Comment: The fields you mentioned is within the root document, or within the array?